# truncate sentence: delete up to, but not including period

Tags: key-bindings, search, cut-copy-paste, cursor-motions

How can I set up a keybinding to delete up to the end of a sentence that ends with a period, but keep the period?

The commands `df.`, `d)`, and `D` all truncate the sentence but don't keep the period. Manually, I can type `d/\.<ENTER>:noh<ENTER>`.

For example: I have this sentence and the cursor is at the position marked by the caret:

```
Scholar X's monograph is a groundbreaking study but I don't like it.
                                               ^
```

I want to type one command (say, `Ds`) and get this:

```
Scholar X's monograph is a groundbreaking study.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With no extra configuration involved, I would just use:

```
c).<Esc>
```

Bonus: It's repeatable with the dot command.

Also bonus: It works on [any POSIX `vi`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html) and is not Vim-specific.

And actually, I would use `<C-[>` (or "Ctrl+[" if you speak Windows) rather than actually pressing the "Escape" key.

Comment: Nice try, but this fails if the document doesn’t begin each sentence on a new line; e.g., `Scholar X’s monograph is a groundbreaking study.  I like it.”` (all on one line). Your command will delete the spaces before “I like it.”

Comment: I start every sentence on a new line, so this does work for me.

Answer (score 8):

`t` and `f` are nice when we are on the same line. If the period is on another line, we're back to `/\.`. If you want to type `ds`, or `cs`, or `ys`, ... it can be done thanks to an operator-pending mode mapping:

```
:onoremap s /\./<cr>
" and for visual mode, with e-1 to exclude the period.
:vnoremap s /\./e-1<cr>
```

But honestly, I'll bind this to `.` instead of `s` as `s` already does something in visual mode.

Answer (score 7):

You had the right idea with `df.`. Of course, `f` goes up to the period like you noticed. If you use `t` (mnemonic un**t**il) instead, it will go forward until the period, but not to it. From `:h t`

```
                            *t*
t{char}         Till before [count]'th occurrence of {char} to the
            right.  The cursor is placed on the character left of
            {char} |inclusive|.
            {char} can be entered like with the |f| command.
```

So if your buffer is like this:

```
Scholar X's monograph is a groundbreaking study but I don't like it.
                                               ^
```

and you type `t.`, you will be here:

```
Scholar X's monograph is a groundbreaking study but I don't like it.
                                                                  ^
```

The `f` and `t` commands mirror eachother very nicely. In fact they're pretty much identical other than `f` moving one further.

- They can both be repeated with `;` and `,`
- They both have uppercase variants that move backwards instead of forwards

Comment: I accepted this before realizing it doesn't work if the sentence ends on another line. Is that possible with these commands?

Comment: I personally think of the mnemonic for `t` as up **t**o

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would do the following:

```
ma)bd`a
^^^^^^^
||||||+ mark a
|||||+  line position
||||+   delete
|||+    go to end of last word
||+     start of next sentence
|+      mark a
+       set a mark
```

Although not one command as you ask, this does if you're used to using marks roll off the fingers with reasonable ease.

Comment: This fails if the last character before the period is *also* a punctuation character; e.g., `I have a fox named "Edward".  He jumped over a dog (which was lazy).`

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the other answers I thought of this:

```
map ds v)2hx
```

Enter visual mode, go to the end of the sentence (even if on subsequent line), back up two characters to exclude the period, and delete.

Comment: This doesn’t work for me. (1) I can’t get `h` to move back up to a previous line. (2) Have you considered the case where the document doesn’t begin each sentence on a new line? My version of `vim` doesn’t recognize (period)(space) as the end of a sentence; it has to be (period)(space)(space). In that case, the `2h` just backs up over the two spaces, and the period still gets deleted. Changing `2h` to `3h` would be a quick fix, but that would fail if there were ever *more than* two spaces after the period.